# Regular expression(Write regular expression for only one alphabet

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I want to write a validation regular expression for strings that come in the format of

SDDDDDD/DDC

Where:

- S - The string should begin with the S character
- DDDDDD - Any digit between 0-9, this could be between 1-6 digits
- DD - Any digit between 0-9, 2 digits mandatory
- C  - Any character between a-zA-Z

For example
S123456/22F

I wrote the following expression:

```
/S[0-9]{1,6}\/[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}/
```

But it does not fit. What is the correct expression to validate such strings?

Comment: the last one is validating only one character if i put S123/22FDDD in place of S123456/22F no error message come that is not correct error message should come i need one character at the end in caps letter

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is

```
^S\d{1,6}/\d{2}[a-zA-Z]$
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.    S[0-9]{1,6}/[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}

Comment: /S[0-9]{1,6}/[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}/g  try this one please

Answer (score 0):

`S\d{1,6}/\d{2}[A-Za-z]` or

`^S\d{1,6}/\d{2}[A-Z]$` if it must match the entire string

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
^S\d{1,6}/\d{2}[A-Z]$
```